# Software that tells you in what country is a given latitude/longitude

Tags: gratis, linux, web-apis, gis, geography

In what country are the coordinates `41.44241, 21.31530` ?

A [manual Google Maps search](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=41.44241,%2021.31530) tells me it is in `Macedonia`.

Is there a program (or library) that would tell me this programmatically?

Requirements:

- If the coordinates are not in a country, it should say `sea` or something appropriate
- For contested areas like Kashmir, anything is fine, I am not picky
- Free
- Works on Linux
- If no library/program is available, a web API can be OK too but it must accept at least 50,000 requests daily

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567539/reverse-geocoding-converting-coordinates-into-address ?

Comment: @KaranGoel: That JavaScript question is about some guy's buggy source code that calls Google Maps API, and how to fix that code. Full-address geocoding sounds overkill, but it is certainly much better than nothing, so feel free to add an answer here about Google Maps API :-)

Comment: Something fundamentally wrong about your request is that you want 50k daily requests for free. If you really have than much quota, you should be expecting to pay.

Comment: @KaranGoel: If I had a week of vacations right now, I would develop a library that does this, and give it away for free (as open source). It is not rocket science, just get a borders map from OpenStreetMap and calculate in which country each point falls.

Comment: It honestly doesn't feel like something that would take a week. But at 1.5 million monthly requests it will definitely won't be free. You'll still have to get your own server instances or whatever.

Comment: @KaranGoel: On this site, "free" means license/subscription fees. Electricity/hardware for your own computer is not counted. By the way, a quick estimation shows that 50k coordinates will probably cost less than 0.01$ of electricity on my laptop.

Comment: Don't want to start an argument, but there is more to servers than electricity. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple method to match a set of latitudes and longitudes is to use [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) and the [Point Sampling Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/)

1. Firstly, download and install QGIS
2. Download and install a spatial dataset of political boundary polygons (for example from [naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/)
3. Create a CSV containing your points and whatever other attributes you're interested in
4. Open QGIS and install the Point Sampling Tool plugin (instructions in the [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html))
5. Add the political boundaries to the project (instructions in the [QGIS docs](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#loading-a-shapefile))
6. Add the CSV of the points of interest (instructions in the [QGIS docs](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#loading-a-delimited-text-file))
7. Use the Point Sampling Tool by clicking the icon [image: Point Sampling Tool icon] in the toolbar
8. Select the attributes from both layers you want to keep in the new file, and create a new shapefile as output
9. Check the `Add created layer to the TOC` button to re-add the data to the map
10. Right click on the newly created layer in the Table of Contents and select `Save Layer As`
11. Select CSV and hit OK and you get a CSV with country points joined to the CSV

Comment: That works perfectly! 50k points takes about half an hour, which is reasonable. Most importantly, it works offline, which is ideal for time/network costs/privacy. First time using QGIS, it is quite intuitive so the steps above are easily performed.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). If you're familiar with Python I'd recommend the [`geopy`](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) library which includes geocoders for a number of services including Yahoo, Google, and OpenStreetMap Nominatum.

Your issue will be the quantity of requests, which will depend on the license of the geocoding service that you use, so you'll have to examine those carefully. For 50 000 addresses per day you may end up having to pay for a service.

For example to use the Google geocoder assuming your points are a latitude/longitude coordinate pair:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

geolocator = GoogleV3()
location = geolocator.reverse((41.44241, 21.31530), exactly_one=True)
print(location.address)
```

If handling the larger volumes of data as @Nicolas Raoul suggests above you should really be downloading a dataset containing political boundaries (for example from [naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/)) and using a GIS system such as [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) to intersect the data with your points.

Comment: Full address reverse geocoding is overkill for what I am trying to achieve. An offline country-level geocoding library would be perfect. It could be as simple as: `IF -32<latitude<-53 AND 164<longitude<180 THEN "New Zealand"`-type code (slightly more complex for some countries). Your QGIS idea sounds exactly like what I need, would you mind detailing it a bit as another answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could also take a look at using the political boundary data from http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/ or the CIA data https://www.evl.uic.edu/pape/data/WDB/